# Haskell >>= operation: why is the function argument required to return another Monad?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, monads

Considering the expression:

```
[0,1..] >>= \i -> [i * 2]
```

In the definition of `>>=` for List, the lambda function `\i -> [i * 2]` is mapped over the list argument via fmap, resulting in a list of lists, `[[0], [2]..]`. So `>>=` needs to flatten the result using a join function in order to return the list: `[0, 2..]`

According to [this source](https://www.schoolofhaskell.com/school/starting-with-haskell/basics-of-haskell/13-the-list-monad): "...the definition of bind in terms of fmap and join works for every monad m: `ma >>= k = join $ fmap k ma`"

So why is it necessary to place the burden of returning a monad on the function supplied to >>=? Why not simply define bind like so?

```
ma >>= k = fmap k ma
```

This way you don't have to deal with flattening the result.

Comment: Because `ma >>= k = join $ fmap k ma` is more powerful. Your variant is just alias to `fmap`, `ma >>= k = fmap k ma ~ (>>=) = flip fmap`.

Comment: It's not burden, it's an opportunity. The whole point of monads is that they are not just functors with `fmap` and `<$>`. Of course in your specific example, those would have sufficed.

Comment: `>>=` wasn't defined out of thin error; a function of type `a -> m b` for a monad `m` is a Kleisli arrow, and its use is firmly grounded in category theory. Monads are useful in programming *because* they "trap" values, making it easy to lift a value into the monad but hard to get out.

Comment: `[0,1..] >>= \i -> [i * 2]` doesn't return `[[0], [2]..]` it returns `[0,2,4,6,8,..]` just like  `fmap (*2)` would do however with the bind operator you have the option to use `return` to make it return a monad properly so `[0,1..] >>= \i -> return [i * 2]` would result `[[0],[2],[4],[6],[8],..]`. Yet with `fmap` its not the case `take 5 $ (\i -> [i * 2]) <$> [0..]` would return `[[0],[2],[4],[6],[8],..]`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

What you're proposing is to simply define the bind operator to be equal to `fmap`, but with arguments swapped:

```
ma >>= k = fmap k ma
-- is equivalent to:
(>>=) = flip fmap
```

In which case, why not just use the `fmap` itself, or its operator form `<$>`?

```
(*2) <$> [0,1..]
> [0,2,4,6,...]
```

However, this does not cover *all* cases where `bind` may be used. The difference is that monads are more powerful than functors. Where functors only let you produce exactly one output for every input, monads let you do all kinds of crazy stuff.

Consider, for example, the following:

```
[0,1,2,3] >>= \i -> [i*2, i*3]
> [0,0,2,3,4,6,6,9]
```

Here, the function produces two values for each input. This cannot be expressed via just `fmap`. This requires `join`ing the resulting values.

Here's another, even less obvious example:

```
[0,1,2,3,4,5] >>= \i -> if i `mod` 2 == 0 then [] else [i]
> [1,3,5]
```

Here, the function either produces a value or doesn't. The empty list is technically still a value in the List monad, yet it cannot be obtained by `fmap`ing the input.

Comment: You *can* get these results with just `fmap`... but it wouldn't be sensible to (e.g. `fmap (\x -> 2*x+1) [0..]` is `[1,3..]`, and `fmap (\x -> x + mod x 2 * (div x 2 - 1)) [0..]` is your `[0,0,2,3,4,6,6,9...]` value). But make the input list finite and all of a sudden the shape changes, which is not an effect `fmap` can have.

Comment: The point was that your can't produce fewer or more than one value with `fmap`.

Comment: I agree that's the point. And I think it's easy to make that point crystal clear: just avoid infinite lists in your examples.

Comment: Well, those were the OP's examples. I was trying to keep close to the original to minimize cognitive overhead.

Answer (score 1):

A major feature of a monad is to be able to "flatten" (`join`). This is necessary to define a nice form of composition.

Consider the composition of two functions with side effects, say in the `IO` monad:

```
foo :: A -> IO B
bar :: B -> IO C
```

If `>>=` was only `fmap` (without the final `join`) pass, the composition

```
\a -> foo a >>= bar
```

would mean

```
\a -> fmap bar (foo a)
-- i.e.
fmap bar . foo
```

which does look as a nice composition, but unfortunately has type `A -> IO (IO C)` ! If we can't flatten the nested `IO`, every composition would add yet another layer, and we would end up with result types of the form `IO (IO (IO ...))` showing the number of compositions.

At best, this would be inconvenient. At worst, this would prevent recursion such as

```
loop = readLn >>= \x -> print x >>= \_ -> loop
```

since it leads to a type with an infinite nesting of `IO`.